# Moving A Pycharm Project

Tags: python, pygame, pycharm

I'm using Pygame with sprites and animations. I have the sprites but I need to put the Pycharm project into the folder that all the sprites are in but whenever I move the project it takes it out of my Pycharm folder and puts it in the folder with sprites which then means when I open up Pycharm I have to go to File Explorer and find the project that uses the sprites and then make a new Pycharm folder to open it. can I get the project in with the sprites and in the pycharm folder.

Comment: Would moving the sprites into the project folder work?

Comment: Legorooj that did work thank you.

Comment: Your welcome. I'll add it as an answer and if you choose it as successful the question will be tagged as answered

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moving the sprites into the project folder should work.